# Can you pass an Angular service as a parameter to a function provided by another Angular service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refactoring, angular-services

I have a bunch of functions throughout my Angular app using mostly the same code. So I decided to create a service which is made of the frequently duplicated code, and takes as parameters the differences.

One of the primary and few differences each of the duplicate functions have is that they use different services.

So for example, in a simplified excerpt, one has:

```
$scope.signin = function(email, password){
        loginSrvc(email, password).execute()
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                if (status == 200){
                ....
```

and one has

```
  $scope.logout = function(){
        $scope.loading = true;
        signoutSrvc().execute()
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                if (status == 200){
                ....
```

but essentially they are the same thing.

I want to be able to pass the services each function is using, for example `loginSrvc`, `signoutSrvc`, etc to an external service which handles all of this sort of code.

**However**, when I pass the service to my new service, it appears on the other end as `undefined`.

My new service looks like:

```
sharedFunctionsApp.factory('serverCommunicationFactory', [function(){
    console.log("serverCommunicationFactory");
    return function(service){
        console.log(service);
        service.execute();
    }
}]);
```

and I pass services to it from other modules (after injecting the `ShareFunctions` module of course) like this:

```
serverCommunicationFactory()(loginSrvc);
```

Yet it still shows as `undefined`.

How can I pass my services to this new shared service?

Comment: after the edit, now its really unclear question,  what do you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can inject other services in a service, just like it :

```
sharedFunctionsApp.factory('yourServiceName', ['theServiceToInject', function(theServiceToInject){
  return {
      yourServiceMethode: function() {
          console.log(theServiceToInject);
          return;
      }
  }
}]);
```

EDIT:

you can also use the injector to inject your services: [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)
and then inject dynamically the service doing something like:

```
var myService = $injector.get('MyServiceName');
```

Comment: But then I have to import a bunch of `Apps` and services. It will be a huge mess if I have to inject 50+ services into the service

Answer (score 0):

yes of course you can inject one service into another.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="startCtrl">

</div>
```

.js

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.factory("firstService",function(){
      return{
        myFunction:function()
        {
            var myVar="Hello from service one";
            return myVar;
        }
    }

});



app.factory("secondService",function(firstService){
      return{
        callToFirstService:function()
        {
            var result=firstService.myFunction();
            return result;
        }
    }

});

app.controller("startCtrl",function($scope,secondService){
     var finalResult= secondService.callToFirstService();
    console.log(finalResult);
});
```

You can check this in working fiddle....

https://jsfiddle.net/codu16t5/

this is a small demo.